# Difference between "свою" and "твою"?

Tags: грамматика, местоимения

How to explain the difference to someone who's not a native Russian speaker?
Example:

- Ты любишь свою маму?
- Ты любишь твою маму?

The second example sounds a bit wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Свой* is used as a possessive pronoun for the agent (not necessarily subject) in the sentence.

> - Я люблю свою маму
> - Солдату приказали принести свою винтовку (*солдат* is not a subject but still the agent for *принести*. There is no agent for *приказали*, so *своя* unequivocally refers to *солдат*)

If there is more than one agent in the sentence, it can be somewhat confusing what does *свой* refer to, though usually the last mentioned agent is assumed.

> - Папа попросил принести свой чемодан (*папа* is only the agent in the sentence, so it's dad's suitcase)
> - Папа попросил маму принести свой чемодан (*папа* and *мама* are both agents to different verbs, so the sentence can be parsed both ways, but most people would assume it's mom's suitcase)

If you are using a non-reflexive possessive pronoun, it should either refer to a third party (*он любит его маму* "he loves his (someone else's) mom") or resolve the ambiguity introduced by multiple agents (*папа попросил маму принести её чемодан*). Otherwise it would sound a bit wrong indeed, as you have correctly noted.

Answer (score 3):

That is easy.We use **свой(свою)** with all personal pronouns.Here **mom** is a close relation of the person ( here the subject ).

> Я люблю **свою** маму. (I love my mum) Ты любишь **свою** маму?(Do you love your mom? )Мы любим **своих** мам.(we love our moms)

That is the case when in English the subject corresponds to the possessive adjective. We **don't** say **ты --твою**.  When it doesn't, we use possessive adjectives according to the meaning. **Mom** is not a relative of the person (the subject ).The agent is not necessarily a subject in the sentence.

> Я видел твою маму вчера. Она видела мою маму.